# Iteration for select and modify in ruby

Tags: ruby, iteration

I have code similar to

```
@a.each{ |n|
   if n == i then
      @b.push n
      n = 2*n
   end
}
```

I want to iterate over an array `@a`, and if some condition `n == i` is true, then use the current element `n` to do `@b.push n`, and then update it to `n = 2*n` in place. How I can iterate for selecting and modifying?

Comment: Can you clarify "update it... in place"? Do you mean you want the value of `n` in `@a` to be replaced by `2*n`, so that `@a` now holds `2*n` instead of `n`?

Comment: why in-place instead of a new array? is the input array humongous?

Comment: Modifying the value of `n` seems to defeat the purpose of iterating `n` over `@a`. Your intention is not clear.

Comment: @mbratch, yes. exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@a.each.with_index do |n, j|
  next unless n == i
  @b.push(i)
  @a[j] = 2 * i
end
```

Answer (score 2):

NArray can do this very fast if the array is large:

```
require 'narray'

# Some sample data:
a = NArray.int(100000).random(10)

i = 8
# b is a "boolean" array that can be used to select or modify
# only certain elements in a
b = a.eq i 

a[b] *= 2
```

If your initial array `@a` is large, and you are worried about performance, you might want to give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

using `each_with_index` solved problem

```
@a.each_with_index{ |n,q|
   if n == i then
      @b.push n
      @a[q] = 2*n
   end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@a.each_with_index do |n, x|
  if n == i
    @b.push n
    @a[x] = 2*n
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below will work :

```
@a.map!{|n| n == i ? (@b.push n; 2*n) : n }
```